# Android Downloading Images from server, got the OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget exception

Tags: android, image, exception, memory, download

In my app, I am downloading images from server. I am getting the following error after downloading 40+ images:

```
 11-03 20:16:17.185: W/dalvikvm(12081): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-03 20:16:17.185: E/AndroidRuntime(12081): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-41
11-03 20:16:17.185: E/AndroidRuntime(12081): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
11-03 20:16:17.185: E/AndroidRuntime(12081):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-03 20:16:17.185: E/AndroidRuntime(12081):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
11-03 20:16:17.185: E/AndroidRuntime(12081):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
11-03 20:16:17.185: E/AndroidRuntime(12081):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
11-03 20:16:17.185: E/AndroidRuntime(12081):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:657)
11-03 20:16:17.185: E/AndroidRuntime(12081):    at com.twintechs.bl.ImageLoader.downloadDrawable(ImageLoader.java:25)
11-03 20:16:17.185: E/AndroidRuntime(12081):    at com.twintechs.itsr.LatestActivity$10.run(LatestActivity.java:332)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Obviously you're out of memory...??

Comment: Are you downloading them to memory or the SD card?

Comment: Actually, I am showing 18 images per view. When user clicks more, then 18 more images are showed on screen. I am storing these images in ArrayList in ImageView and Drawable pair form. I m not storing on SD Card.

Comment: I am using the following piece of code to download image:

URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setConnectTimeout(7000);
connection.connect();
BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
imageDrawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, imageUrl);

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the bitmaps one at a time and then move them off to the SD card. There's simply not enough room in memory to store all those bitmaps.